# Gmail keyboard shortcut activation while typing on the search box

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I have keyboard shortcuts enabled for the standard Gmail web interface. I consider myself a search box power user and use it to search emails with long commands. However, both in Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS, while using the search bar in Gmail, I often experience **mid-typing jump from search box to activating keyboard shortcuts**.

I suspect this is because the focus somehow switches out of the search box. It is super annoying, since I accidentally archive, mute, start replying to an email, start adding a new task, or start a new email. I type at an above average speed, so by the time I notice this mode switch, I have already sent many keystrokes in.

Is this a common problem, and is there a solution? Any suggestions as to how to track the cause of this problem down?

Comment: Agreed! This is super-annoying, and has caused me to accidentally delete or archive emails, etc. Would love to know what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for this, I thought I was going insane. This has been happening for years in Gmail. It's crazy they haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: @NurL can you upvote the Q? Indeed this problem hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: @Memming:  I did

Comment: Agreed. Super annoying bug (in an otherwise great interface!).